# Node Child Process Spawn "TypeError: Bad argument TypeError"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I run the following code with node:

```
var command = "/home/myScript.sh";
fs.exists(command, function(exists){
    if(exists)
    {
        var childProcess =  spawn(command, []); //this is line 602
    }
});
```

I get this error:

```
[critical error]: TypeError: Bad argument TypeError: Bad argument
    at TypeError (native)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:274:26)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at /home/simulations/GUIServer/Server/SocketServer.js:602:28
    at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:212:19)
TypeError: Bad argument
    at TypeError (native)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:274:26)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at /home/simulations/GUIServer/Server/SocketServer.js:602:28
    at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:212:19)
```

My versions are:

- Node Version:  v4.2.6
- Express Version:  4.12.0

Running on **Linux x64**.

The permissions for the file are 755:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2502 2016-12-06 17:12 myScript.sh
```

and I am running as **root**.

Any ideas on what could be causing this error? What's weird is I think it was working before...

Comment: What system are you running this on? Because I know on OSX the `/home` folder is read only which could be why it is throwing an error.

Comment: Hey @Minidodds! Thanks for the suggestion! I'm running on linux :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a silly answer... ***"command" was undefined***. Here's why:

I had `var command` at the top of my loop, then I tried to redefine `command` later on. This was somehow causing `command` to be undefined. Here's what I was doing:

**WRONG**

```
var command = "/home/myScript.sh";
fs.exists(command, function(exists){
    if(exists)
    {
        //"command" here is UNDEFINED!?
        var childProcess =  spawn(command, []);
    }else
    {
        var command = "something new"; //THIS IS WHAT CAUSED THE PROBLEM
    }
});
```

**RIGHT**

```
var command = "/home/myScript.sh";
fs.exists(command, function(exists){
    if(exists)
    {
        var childProcess =  spawn(command, []);
    }else
    {
        command = "something new"; //FIXED
    }
});
```